# Does Flyway support InterSystems Cache Database migration?

Tags: flyway, intersystems

Flyway DB migration tool supports wide range of databases. I'm wondering whether Flyway supports **InterSystems Cache Database** to handle basic DB migration tasks? Though it's not explicitly mentioned in flyway documentation, since flyway uses common **JDBC drivers and Plain Old SQL migration scripts** technically (in high level) it should support basic DB migration of any SQL supported databases. Thought of reach out to experts before giving its a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No (at least not at this time). It is perfectly capable of being extended to support any database with JDBC connections and SQL migration scripts, and it is possible to fork the community codebase and add support for another database without too much work. See here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/contributingDatabaseSupport - which also explains why not every database will be supported in future.